# How to improve images loading issues. is there any cache like solution

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I have built an **iOS app using Parse.com**.

In my app i have displayed a lot of data from network.

*To load the data speedily i used cache `kPFCachePolicyCacheThenNetwork`*. It loads data fine but while scrolling ***images are takes some amount of time to load.***

First white image and then image loads.

***`Is there any solution like cache to display images in imageviews with out interruption.`***

Thanks.

Comment: you can use SDWebimage library

Comment: use afnetworking +uiimageview category its  good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I write the code with the help of gcd , you just have to pass the object of imageView and pass the url , it manages all the things, like cache.

```
-(void)downloadingServerImageFromUrl:(UIImageView*)imgView AndUrl:(NSString*)strUrl{


strUrl = [strUrl encodeUrl];

NSString* theFileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.png",[[strUrl lastPathComponent] stringByDeletingPathExtension]];


NSFileManager *fileManager =[NSFileManager defaultManager];

NSString *fileName = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"tmp/%@",theFileName]];



imgView.backgroundColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
UIActivityIndicatorView *actView = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhite];
[imgView addSubview:actView];
[actView startAnimating];

CGSize boundsSize = imgView.bounds.size;
CGRect frameToCenter = actView.frame;
// center horizontally
if (frameToCenter.size.width < boundsSize.width)
frameToCenter.origin.x = (boundsSize.width - frameToCenter.size.width) / 2;
else
frameToCenter.origin.x = 0;




 // center vertically
if (frameToCenter.size.height < boundsSize.height)
frameToCenter.origin.y = (boundsSize.height - frameToCenter.size.height) / 2;
else
frameToCenter.origin.y = 0;

actView.frame = frameToCenter;



dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
dispatch_async(queue, ^{

NSData *dataFromFile = nil;
NSData *dataFromUrl = nil;

dataFromFile = [fileManager contentsAtPath:fileName];
if(dataFromFile==nil){
    dataFromUrl=[[[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strUrl]] autorelease];                      
}

dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

    if(dataFromFile!=nil){
        imgView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:dataFromFile];
    }else if(dataFromUrl!=nil){
        imgView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:dataFromUrl];  
        NSString *fileName = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"tmp/%@",theFileName]];

        BOOL filecreationSuccess = [fileManager createFileAtPath:fileName contents:dataFromUrl attributes:nil];       
        if(filecreationSuccess == NO){
            NSLog(@"Failed to create the html file");
        }

    }else{
        imgView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"NO_Image.png"];  
    }
    [actView removeFromSuperview];
    [actView release];
    [imgView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
});
});
```

}

Comment: strUrl = [strUrl encodeUrl]; .. No visable @interface for NSString declare selector 'encodeURL'

Comment: Sorry, I was using category for convert string to encode, so it can remove spaces from the url string.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [**SDWebImage**](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) for doing this.

Also you can use [**NSCache**](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/NSCache_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for caching purpose.

Comment: +1 for `SDWebImage`, which actually offers both `NSCache` based cache as well as persistent storage cache. If someone's already using AFNetworking, then its `UIImageView` category isn't bad, but I think `SDWebImage` offers a few additional features if all you need is a cache for images.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can use [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) UIImageview category and you are sorted

you can also disable caching of a particular image usually needed if you edit an existing image and then dwnload it from same URL, by manipulagting its

```
-(void)setImageWithURL:(NSURL *)url
       placeholderImage:(UIImage *)placeholderImage
```

as mentioned in this [blog](http://codefriends.blogspot.in/2013/05/how-to-disable-caching-of-particular.html)

An other option could be [ASImageView](https://github.com/Amar11s/ASImage) with facility to refresh cache.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code for loading image in background . check this [Code](https://github.com/nicklockwood/AsyncImageView)

Comment: pls try giving some details becoz if link expires your ans becomes useless

Answer (score 0):

you should use EGOImageLoading([EGOImageLoading](https://github.com/enormego/EGOImageLoading)) for lazy loading of images and can save images using NSUserDefaults.

It is best way i advice as i have used it in many projects.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to say it, but Parse is already doing all these things. Parse uses AFNetworking to get the images, puts them in an NSCache, and uses disk caching very aggressively so that redundant network trips are completely avoided (the version is part of the URL, so Parse doesn't even need to use an if-modified-since GET).

The biggest issue you might be encountering is that PFFile throttles downloads to only download 3 images at a time. After experimentation this was the best number because it ensured incremental feedback to the user and avoided a nasty issue where some iOS devices would get very poor performance after too many threads. The best advice I could offer you would be to prefetch some images if possible. As mentioned earlier, PFFile images are very aggressively cached. The kPFCachePolicy... stuff only affects queries which might grow stale; the images those queries point to are always cached (though only initially downloaded on demand).